# rails crash: uninitialized constant ActionController::Rescue::ClassMethods::Response

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After i wrote a simple rails helloworld application and tried to start,  the rails version=2.3.5, and disabled AR like:

```
config.frameworks -= [ :active_record, :active_resource, :action_mailer ]
```

it throwed exception like below,

```
[FATAL 2011-04-29 17:46:43] merpro_client: /!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Fri Apr 29 17:46:43 +0800 2011
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
uninitialized constant ActionController::Rescue::ClassMethods::Response
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:440:in `load_missing_constant'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:64:in `call_with_exception'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:90:in `dispatch'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:93:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:114:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:34:in `run'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:46:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:50:in `service'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:111
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
script/server:3
```